# Pagination in blog comments in sitefinity

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity

I have created a blog in sitefinity. I have multiple blog posts. In each post , i may have more than 100 comments. I want something that i could limit the comments that show to 50 and a pager control should show in last of comments section to show other comments, How can i achieve this is sitefinity.

Answer (score 0):

If you log in to the admin of your site and go to Settings -> Advanced -> CommentsModule, you can set some global settings for the comments widget including enabling paging and setting the number of comments per page.

[image]